# Flight booking with XXX as given name on passport

Tags: air-travel, turkish-airlines

I am booking a flight for me and my family.  My daughter’s given name is on her Canadian passport as 'XXX' while her full name is in the surname field.

What should we put as her first name while booking the flight. Should I put 'XXX' or use her actual first name?

Comment: Use the same info as found on the passport.

Comment: Did you request the passport to be issued this way? Depending where she will travel or live in the future, you may save her from many bureaucratic hassles if you can get her a new passport that has both a surname and given name.